# How to add username password to connection string adodb

Tags: excel, vba

i need to add a username and password to my ADODB connection

```
With cn
    .ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server}; " & _
    " SERVER=MyServerName;" & _
    " DATABASE=db;" & _
    " Trusted_connection=YES"
    .Open
End With
```

Comment: uid for userid and pwd for password

Comment: reference here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34389720/connection-string-for-sql-server-2014-express-vba

Comment: @Warcupine Perhaps you should combine and expand those two comments into [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57039748/how-to-add-username-password-to-connection-string-adodb#new-answer)?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good resource to find possible connection strings: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

You can try e.g.:

```
With cn
    .ConnectionString = "DRIVER={SQL Server}; " & _
    " SERVER=MyServerName;" & _
    " DATABASE=db;" & _
    " User Id=myUsername;" & _
    " Password=myPassword"
    .Open
End With
```